# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZipFile'

Tags: python

just like i said,it's a very strange question.i hope you guys could help me solve this question  thanks

**the following is my code:**

```
import os
import zipfile

filename = "E:\\test.zip"
currdir = "E:\\vpn\\"

os.chdir(currdir)

tfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w')
files = os.listdir(currdir)
for f in files:
    tfile.write(f)

for f in tfile.namelist():
    print "added %s"%f

tfile.close()
```

**the error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pydemo\src\gzip\zipfile.py", line 7, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\pydemo\src\gzip\zipfile.py", line 14, in <module>
tfile = zipfile.ZipFile.(filename, 'w')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZipFile'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You called your script `zipfile.py`, which means it is trying to import itself. Change the name of the file to basically anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Your module is importing itself as zipfile. Call it something other than zipfile.py

Comment: thanks for your help. and i find when i run this script , it will generate a .pyc file , i have to delete this .pyc file before i run a new script